# Insert space before three zeros

Tags: javascript, jquery, space, zero

I am working on jquery slider to take min and max price and I need help to insert space before
each 3 zeros.

for example:
I need 5000 to become 5 000

50000 = 50 000

Can you help me? Thanks alot

Comment: what exactly you want ? in php or js ?

Comment: Sorry, javascript, I thought it will be written to the start of title, like StackOverflow does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write:

```
var splitIndex = (s.length + 2) % 3 + 1;
s = s.substr(0, splitIndex) + s.substr(splitIndex).replace(/\d\d\d/g, ' $&');
```